# PHP's PDO::fetch() running out of memory

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, ibm-midrange

I'm selecting 19 columns from an AS400 (IBM iSeries database) table. The query runs fine, the total row count is less than 17,000.
However, as soon as I run

```
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
```

PHP runs out of memory (512 megs). The script doesn't even take a second to crash - something uses up every bit of memory immediately.

I can fetch more columns from a different table with a total of 150,000 rows returned (using the same fetch() command) and memory consumption remains stable at around 500 KB.
However something about that other select fetch completely annihilates the process.

I'm using the iSeries ODBC drivers from IBM on 64 bit linux.
Any suggestions for further troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I've isolated the issue to the column causing this - it's a CHARACTER field with length of 4. The record breaking the fetch actually has a null in that field. Might be some misunderstanding on the part of the driver on how to handle nulls.

Comment: What are you doing with `$row`?

Comment: What is `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` set to? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: You are sure that there is no column inside the table which uses a lot of memory? Some binary object stored in a blob or similar?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Can't do anything with it - php runs out of memory on that line.

Comment: @erg, good thought but columns are just varchars, decimals and integers

Comment: @jaswrks I'm not querying a mysql database so that setting is unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a known problem with IBM's 64 bit drivers:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54007

In lieu of porting the fix suggested in the bug report and recompiling PHP, one can use workaround like adding an IFNULL function call to fields that can be nulls. Not exactly a solution but it'll have to do until IBM figure this out (if they do).

**UPDATE**: In case anyone runs into this issue, apparently while the iSeries odbc driver does have this issue (and is probably never getting updated), there is a new connection software called IBM i Access Client which comes with a better working ODBC driver.

Instructions on where to find the download are here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010355

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do this:

```
select case 
   when offending_field is null then 'NULL' 
   else offending_field end as offending_field
   from TABLE_NAME where CONDITION.
```